# Using another library from inside a Google Apps Script library (dependencies)?

Tags: google-apps-script

This might sound dim, so please do bear with me, but I can't seem to find anything on this on the interwebs, no matter how hard I search.

I've spent the past 6 months building a series of long and complicated scripts to do a lot of the sysadmin gruntwork in my org, based on input into a series of Google forms. What this has led to is a large number of standalone scripts with functions copied and pasted between them rather than shared. In the event that a major API update happened, I would have to make edits to upwards of 50 separate scripts. Silly, I know, but it started off as a small project and then snowballed.

I now want to build a script library and publish it so I can re-create a lot of my work in a more sensible and coherent way, and make future edits much more manageable. The only issue is that about half of my scripts (anything involving user impersonation) also needs to call the OAuth2 library v26 in order to work (created by Eric Koleda, to give credit where it's due, because it's excellent).

Does anyone know if we can either 'automate' a dependency within a library (similar to how brew installs dependencies for a given formula) or whether, if I list it as a dependency in the readme.md and the user has the advanced service enabled, the functions in my library will be able to use the functions from the OAuth2 library?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try importing the OAuth2 library into your own library? I haven't tried something like this before, but I can't think of any reason why that shouldn't work. If that doesn't work, please specify what you have tried and what the results were.

Comment: Hi Casper. You don't really import libraries in Google Apps Script unless I'm missing something very basic - you enable them in the script console, and this allows for calling functions from this library within your script. When you publish a library that ability to enable in the console isn't there, afaik, hence the concern.

Comment: I've added the OAuth2 library to one of my existing libraries without any issue. It might help if you specify how you publish your script as publishing is not necessary for library usage.